# Powershell to query computers in domain and get cert value

Tags: powershell

we're looking at getting a list of all computers in the environment and see what certificates are on the computers. We will need to know if they're sha1 or sha2 hash.

I've looked online and can't see if this is even possible?

Help please

Comment: That's brilliant, thank you. At the risk of sounding cheeky I've tried to run this from a text file which is a list of computers and run the check and export the host name operating system service pack and sha cert status .. Is there a way of combining ur scripts for this, please

Comment: Show what you've come up with (post your script) or ask a new question

Answer (score 4):

You can inspect the algorithm like so:

```
$Cert = Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\My\ | Select -First 1
if($Cert.SignatureAlgorithm.FriendlyName -like "sha2*"){
    Write-Host "SHA2 sig, all good"
}
```

To get all the computers in the domain, you can just use `Get-ADComputer`:

```
$Computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter {Enabled -eq $True}
foreach($Computer in $Computers){
    # Run your check against each $Computer in here
}
```

You can then either use PSRemoting, and execute the check on the remote computer:

```
$pss = New-PSSession -ComputerName remotemachine.domain.tld
Invoke-Command -Session $pss -ScriptBlock {
    # code to check certs go here
}
```

Or you can connect directly to the remote certificate store from your own machine:

```
$CertStore = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store "\\$ComputerName\My","LocalMachine"
$CertStore.Open([System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.OpenFlags]::ReadOnly)
foreach($Cert in $CertStore.Certificates){
    # once again, inspect $Cert.SignatureAlgorithm
}
$CertStore.Close()
```